# Hide drop-down menus in using id number

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-crispy-forms

I passed a list `[object1, object2, ...]` to a drop-down menu. When I pressed on `F12` with the desire of knowing the id of `object1` which is `Total number of clients` in the following HTML code. I want to use that id in a JS file. How could I generate one id for each item of the list. Otherwise, what can I use in the JS file instead of an id number for  `Total number of clients`?

```html
<div class="select-wrapper select initialized"><span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-655bff26-fb5b-1642-ddeb-41bd1b4ab105" value="Total number of clients">
  <ul id="select-options-655bff26-fb5b-1642-ddeb-41bd1b4ab105" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 100px; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
    <li class="active selected"><span>Total number of clients</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total new loans</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total renewals</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total debit fees</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total brokerage fees</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total interest</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total accounts receivable</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total active accounts receivable</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total special accounts receivable</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total accounts loss</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total completed loans</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total terminated loans</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total suspended loans</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total delayed fees</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>Total denied fees</span></li>
  </ul>
  <select class="select initialized" id="id_type_choice" name="type_choice">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Total number of clients</option>
    <option value="1">Total new loans</option>
    <option value="2">Total renewals</option>
    <option value="3">Total debit fees</option>
    <option value="4">Total brokerage fees</option>
    <option value="5">Total interest</option>
    <option value="6">Total accounts receivable</option>
    <option value="7">Total active accounts receivable</option>
    <option value="8">Total special accounts receivable</option>
    <option value="9">Total accounts loss</option>
    <option value="10">Total completed loans</option>
    <option value="11">Total terminated loans</option>
    <option value="12">Total suspended loans</option>
    <option value="13">Total delayed fees</option>
    <option value="14">Total denied fees</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is how I generate the drop-down menu :

### settings.py

```
STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (0, _('Total number of clients')),
    (1, _('Total new loans')),
    (2, _('Total renewals')),
    (3, _('Total debit fees')),
    (4, _('Total brokerage fees')),
    (5, _('Total interest')),
    (6, _('Total accounts receivable')),
    (7, _('Total active accounts receivable')),
    (8, _('Total special accounts receivable')),
    (9, _('Total accounts loss')),
    (10, _('Total completed loans')),
    (11, _('Total terminated loans')),
    (12, _('Total suspended loans')),
    (13, _('Total delayed fees')),
    (14, _('Total denied fees')),
)
```

### forms.py

```
class StatisticsBaseForm(forms.Form):
    type_choice = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Type"), choices=settings.STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES, initial=0, required=False)
    period = forms.ChoiceField(label="Period", choices=settings.PERIODS, initial='week', required=False)
    from_regular_product = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ProductConfig.objects.filter(pk=-1), required=False,
        label=_('Product'))
    from_special_product = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ProductConfig.objects.filter(pk=-1), required=False,
        label=_('Product'))
    product_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=settings.LOANWOLF_PRODUCT_TYPE_CHOICES, required=False,
        initial='regular', label=_('Product type'))
    debit_frequency = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=settings.LOANWOLF_PRODUCT_DEBIT_FREQUENCIES_CHOICES,
        required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StatisticsBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'row'
        self.helper.layout = StatisticalToolsLayout

        company = get_current_company()
        regular_products = company.available_products.filter(
            is_active=True, product_type='regular')
        special_products = company.available_products.filter(
            is_active=True, product_type='special')

        self.fields['from_regular_product'].queryset = regular_products
        self.fields['from_special_product'].queryset = special_products

        if regular_products:
            self.fields['from_regular_product'].initial = \
                settings.LOANWOLF_EXTERNAL_REQUEST_DEFAULT_PRODUCT_INDEX

        if special_products:
            self.fields['from_special_product'].initial = \
                settings.LOANWOLF_EXTERNAL_REQUEST_DEFAULT_PRODUCT_INDEX

    class Meta:
        model = Statistics
        fields = '__all__'
```

### formlayouts.py

```
StatisticalToolsLayout = \
        CardContent(
            Row(
                Column('type_choice', css_class="s2"),
            ),
            Row(
                Column('period', css_class="s2"),
                Column('product_type', css_class="s2"),
                Column(
                    'from_regular_product',
                    'from_special_product',
                    css_class="s4"),
                Column('debit_frequency', css_class="s2"),
            ),
            CardAction(
                Div(
                    Button('apply', _('Apply'), css_class='waves-effect waves-light btn white-text'),
                    css_class="right-align"),
            ),
        )
```

### HTML

```
<div class="row main-content">
    <div class="col s10">
        <div class="card">
            <h5>{{ form.form_title }}</h5>
            {% crispy form form.helper %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have different types of possible requests in the drop-down menu `Type`. For instance, if `Total number of loan is selected`, then some other drop-down menus will be hidden, while other will be showed up. However, I need an id number to do such thing (http://jsfiddle.net/jadendreamer/5SArB/). Do I need to generate ids for all item in  `STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES`?

Please let me know if something is missing.

---

The question is simple ... How could I generate an id number for each element in  STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES in knowing that `type_choice = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Type"), choices=settings.STATISTICS_TYPE_CHOICES, initial=0, required=False)` give us a drop-down menu and the ids are used in a JS file?

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 

    $("#id_type_choice").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});

function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 0)
        $("#div_id_period, #div_id_product_type").hide();
    else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 1)
        $("#div_id_period").hide();
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 2)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 3)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 4)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 5)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 6)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 7)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 8)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 9)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 10)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 11)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 12)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 13)
    //else if ($("#id_type_choice").val() == 14)
    //else
        //$("#parentPermission").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be using javascript anyway, presumably you will have jquery, you can just select only the items that you aren't hiding.

I assume that you are going to hide certain options with certain values, which you can hide with:

```
$('#id_type_choice option[value="10"]').hide();
```

You can get as specific as you like with that, like the ID of the parent.  You can then count all the options that are not hidden.

```
var optCount = $('#id_type_choice option:visible').length
```

Comment: Could you make an example in assuming that I will select value=0, and I want to hide `div_id_product_type`, `div_id_product` and `div_id_debit_frequency`? If so, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. I was assuming you were trying to hide certain choices, and count those that were left.  If you have multiple select dropdowns, the same method can be used for those.  Just replace `#id_type_choice` with whatever id you are using for your select element, and replace the 10 with 0 if that's which one you want to hide.  Am I misunderstanding what you are asking?

Comment: I think I found something, but it did not working entirely. I will put my what I have done so far. Could you give me more suggestions to fix my problem?